# Creating users from database gives me random results

Tags: linux, perl, unix, centos

I had this script which worked perfectly until today.

I am trying to automate the creation of Linux users. I do it like this:

```
my $sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE updated = 0';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$sth->execute();
#

while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {

    #print $row[0],"\n";

    my @chars = ( '0' .. '9', 'A' .. 'F' );
    my $len = 12;
    my $hash;

    while ( $len-- ) {
        $hash .= $chars[ rand @chars ]
    }

    system( "/usr/sbin/useradd -g mygroup -d /home/newusers/$hash -s /sbin/nologin $hash" );
    system( "echo $hash:$hash | /usr/sbin/chpasswd" );

    my $sql_hash_update =
            "UPDATE users SET hash = '"
            . $hash
            . "', updated = 1 WHERE id = '"
            . $row[0]
            . "'";

    my $sth_hash_update = $dbh->prepare( $sql_hash_update );

    $sth_hash_update->execute();
}
```

This has worked flawlessly for a week. It is executed once every minute in the crontab.

Now it just overwrites the directory and adds the owner as some sort of random numbers.

Example:

Executed once:

> User created: AEB7F3BDED52 (exists)
>
> Folder created: /home/AEB7F3BDED52
>
> Owner of the folder: 652350688667 (does not exist as user actually)

Executed twice:

> User created: AD1B583F6062 (exists)
>
> Folder created: /home/AD1B583F6062
>
> Owner of the folder: 1013 (does not exist)

And so on. This random behaviour didn't happen before. I have also halted every other script to make sure there are no interferences. It only happens here. I am clueless because of the randomness of the results. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: After resetting the script works again.

Comment: Start by using placeholders for your SQL, and move the `prepare` outside of the loop. You also don't need to make `@chars` lexical inside of the loop, it never changes. Then replace the `system` calls with `print` to see what's going on.

Comment: @simbabque: `@chars` can go outside the loop, but not `$len`

Comment: @Borodin yes, I forgot about the while. But that can be rewritten to `$hash .= $chars[ rand @chars ] for 1 .. $len` and then it doesn't change.

Comment: Do you use `srand` at all? I think you should show your complete program.

Comment: @Borodin This is the complete program outside of database connection.

Comment: @simbabque Already debugged how you said and it prints what it should be printing

Comment: I find it odd that you are directing the command to put the folder in /home/newusers, but the folders are in /home.   Maybe -b would work better?   Also, is it possible that the random number is the UID ( the numerical value of the username)?   Although the number in the first example seems way to large for that, I'm not sure if that is the real number or something you just typed.  Do a `stat /path/to/file` and let use see the results.  You may want to add the printout that simbaque requested... that would help us debug. Thx.

Comment: @FrankRalphBob yes the second number is the UID, the first number I have no idea. Also I have resetted the server and everything works just fine again.

Comment: *"This is the complete program outside of database connection"* Then ***please always add*** `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` to the top of every Perl program you write, especially before asking others for help to fix it.

Comment: @Borodin there is also use string and use warnings 'all' but they return nothing. I though this was assumed.

Comment: @prgrm: It should be, but mostly it is not. The majority of inexperienced coders seem to prefer to write "on the edge" and shun the help of Perl itself in debugging their work. I had no reason to think you were any different, especially since your program was in such a mess before I tidied it up.

Comment: @FrankRalphBob you mean stat path to my perl script right?   File: ‘user.pl’
  Size: 1456            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 3672909     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-03-13 15:58:57.933518952 +0100
Modify: 2017-03-13 15:55:16.000000000 +0100
Change: 2017-03-13 15:55:17.579406272 +0100
 Birth: -

Comment: @prgrm  Actually, I need you to stat the user directory you were making - that would give us some more information.  However, since it is suddenly working after you "reset" - not sure if any of this is an issue or not.  If you cannot reproduce the error, most of this is moot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting the server solved the problem, so I assume this has to do with Linux and not with the code.